# Set GridLayout background colours dynamically Android

Tags: android, dynamic, grid-layout

I have a GridLayout of 8x8 cells and I want to control each one's background colour dynamically. I have written most of my java code and am confident I can get it to give me an array with 64 colours in it for the backgrounds to be taken from. How do I take these values and change the background colour of the GridLayout cells at the end of my code?

Just to clarify, this is for an API of 14 or higher, I'm writing it specifically for my Galaxy S2, though it should work with any android phone with an API of 14+.

I'm happy to post up any code that might help but I think the question is sufficient alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GridLayout` will not help you with this.

What you have to do is make sure the `View`s all fill their cells.  Then you can call `setBackgroundColor()` on those `View`s.

Comment: I am not using a GridView, I am using a GridLayout. I'm quite sure they are different things.

Comment: Sorry for misreading it.  The answer is much the same however; you have to set the background on the individual views that fill the cells.  None of Android's layouts have any type of "cell background" built into the layout.

Comment: I'm new to all of this so I'm still unsure what you mean. These views, what exactly are they and how do I control them? Do I have to use an Adapter of some sort? I've been searching the internet madly looking for clues or even perhaps an example and I've filled my head with so much nonsense that I'm not sure where I am any more! If you could show me a simple example it would help a lot.

Comment: Every visual gadget in Android - CheckBox, EditText, ImageView, even layouts - all derive from View.  Every child of your GridLayout is a View.  I'm saying you generally have to set the background on those children rather than on the GridLayout itself.  If the children are too small to fill their cells - i.e., there is space left over - then wrap those children inside of something else that will fill the cell, and set the background on that.

Comment: Any chance you could show me a very simple example of what you mean, with just one or two cells perhaps? Perhaps my brain is fried but I don't follow what you're saying.